# Link to a catch-all route in Symfony 4 from Twig

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In my config/routes.yaml I setup a route like this:

```
frontend:
  path: /{path}
  controller: App\Controller\FrontendController::index
  requirements:
    path: .*
```

It's a kind of catch-all or fallback route now which I need in my project.

Is it possible to define some kind of reverse URL? E.g. when I want to link to the named route from within a Twig template:

```
{{ path('frontend') }}
```

I currently run into an error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("path") to generate a URL for route "frontend".").

Obviously. Can I define a default target path like "`/`" in the YAML context? (Instead of just hardcoding it into the template everytime).

Comment: Look at the yaml examples [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#giving-placeholders-a-default-value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a default value to your path in your **YAML** :

```
frontend:
    path: /{path}
    controller: App\Controller\FrontendController::index
    defaults: { path : ''}
    requirements:
      path: .*
```

Or if your route is configured using **Annotations** :

```
* @Route("/{path}", defaults={"path"=""})
```

Comment: Dear Dylan, thanks. Would you please update your answer to reflect my exact routes.yaml example i've given? Just replace your YAML example with "defaults: { path: '' }" - this works.